# How to move a watermark to a video location and stop?

Tags: ffmpeg

I made the watermark animation, but I want it to stop at a specific point in the video, wait 10 seconds and fade out. The code I'm using is this:

```
ffmpeg -y -r 60 -loop 1 -i 2.jpg -i logo2.png -filter_complex "overlay = 0: 'if (gte (t, 1), (overlay_h + (t-1) * 125), NAN) '"-shortest -c: v libx264 -t 20 test14.mp4
```

The animation works, but I can't stop singing and disappear. Can you help me?

Comment: `But I can't stop singing?` could you elaborate?

Comment: Gostaria de fazer uma animação de marca dágua, até aparecer totalmente, depois parar por 10 segundos e desaparecer com efeito fadeout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i 2.jpg -loop 1 -i logo2.png -filter_complex "[1]fade=out:st=15:d=1[ol];[0][ol]overlay=W*5/100:'-h+clip(t*H/5,0,H*95/100)'" -c: v libx264 -t 20 test14.mp4`

This scrolls the watermark vertically down from 0 to 5 seconds; it then rests for 10 seconds, and then fades out in 1 second.

Comment: Great, the watermark stopped but didn't disappear, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Edited cmd for fade.

Comment: Thank you, helped me a lot. Already marked as done, could you now help me with this solution, Loop filter https://superuser.com/questions/1502609/how-to-filter-loop-in-watermarke-ffmpeg ?