# How to filter loop in watermark with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, watermark

I need to create a loop filter, but I don't know how, I have this code that already works without the loop filter:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i backgroud.jpg -loop 1 -i logomark.png -filter_complex"[1]fade=out:st=15:d=0.5[ol];[0][ol]overlay='-h+clip(t*H/5,-10,H*20/100)':W*5/100"-c:v libx264 -t 20 test23.mp4`

But I need the loop to be in filter_complex, it would look something like this:

`ffmpeg -y -framerate 60 -loop 1 -i backgroud.jpg -i logomark.png -filter_complex "[1]-loop=1,fade=out:st=15:d=0.5[ol];[0][ol]overlay='-h+clip(t*H/5,-10,H*20/100)':W*5/100"-c:v libx264 -t 20 test23.mp4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `"[1]loop=-1:1:0,fade=out:st=15:d=0.5[ol];[0][ol]overlay='-h+clip(t*H/5,-10,H*20/100)':W*5/100:shortest=1"`.

(Note that you're swapped the order of the X and Y expressions in overlay filter. That may lead to unexpected results.)

Comment: Yes, I modified it for a watermark to run horizontally.

Comment: You are the best. I am very grateful for your help, it worked perfectly. This error was displayed: No such filter: '-loop' Error initializing complex filters. Invalid argument
This solution worked for me.-> https://superuser.com/a/1502651/1112937

Comment: There was a typo in your cmd which I carried over. Corrected.

Comment: Mais uma vez, obrigado!!!